# how to find symbol of TRAP_BRKPT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash

i have a crash on iOS from the wild which looks something like the following

```
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: TRAP_BRKPT at 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '', reason: ''

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                              0x002bf4d8 0xdb000 + 1983704
1   MyApp                              0x002bf4f4 0xdb000 + 1983732
2   MyApp                              0x004e17ef 0xdb000 + 4220911
```

first question: I'm under the impression SIGTRAP is related to the debugger. how does this happen in production?

I am able to sylbolicate correctly, but not this `TRAP_BRKPT at 0xe7ffdefe`
I think knowing what lives at `0xe7ffdefe` will help me figure out what's going on. so the the second question is how do i find out what is living at `0xe7ffdefe`?

I've tried running

`atos -l -arch armv7 -o ./MyApp 0xe7ffdefe`

and got the output

```
0x00004014 (in MyApp)
0x0000400a (in MyApp)
```

**Edit:**
figured i might as well provide the symbolicated results

```
0   MyApp 0x000000010027c5d8 MyController.viewDidLoad() -> () (MyViewController.swift:26) 
1   MyApp 0x000000010027c5f8 @objc MyViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (MyViewController.swift:0)
```

where line 26 is `self.webView.loadHTMLString(self.staticScreen.body, baseURL: nil)`

Comment: The TRAP_BRKPT is pretty much a red herring. You'll just have to use the symbolication and debug from there. You have not shown what that gives you, so it's impossible to help.

Comment: hey @matt i updated with the symbolicated logs. i'd still like to find out what's at `0xe7ffdefe` though. thanks for your time